# any decent graph libraries for C++?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, graph

I wish to generate a graph with a date on the X axis and price on the Y, are there any decent libraries out there which will help me accomplish this with very little overhead?

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graph drawing C++ library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like qwt, but this is not low overhead. maybe gplot, but give more info about your contaxt perharps.

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

http://gplot.sourceforge.net/